# Glyphs in converted PDFs with Apache PDFBox are abnormal in centOS-ARM

Tags: java, arm, pdfbox

I used `org.apache.pdfbox fontbox 2.0.22` and `org.apache.pdfbox pdfbox 2.0.22` to convert PDF to pictures, which can be converted normally in centOS and windows, but in centOS-ARM, the converted pictures are abnormal.
[image]

Below is the link to the full picture.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IAa_VuHXA592AK_fkE6ur5wLq6QJ8KZe/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rMJtaA4CL5yFQLCRcgBJF2aVe0AUsik4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I read the fonts under /usr/share/fonts, centos and centos-arm fonts are the same, both are the system default (/usr/share/fonts/dejavu), I also tried to put the ttf font under windows Copy to centos-arm, but the converted picture is still abnormal. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1miGy3oSjdQWWG34zeu4C1rypl988ToRr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What java version are you using, can you update it?

Comment: Do you have this effect with all PDFs or only with the one shown? Does it also happen with the command line utilities (pdfbox-app PDFToImage)?

Comment: All pdfs are like this, but the same pdf, the same program, is good in centos or windows, centos7.6-ARM is not good。I am using java version "1.8.0_281".

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)，jdk-8u281-linux-aarch64.tar.gz.

Comment: I haven't tried the command line yet, I will reply you after I try

Comment: Hello, I tried using PDFToImage on the command line, using pdfbox-app-2.0.22.jar, java version "1.8.0_281". Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09), jdk -8u281-linux-aarch64.tar.gz, there is still a problem with the converted picture, but it is good on windows. In the picture, the left side is the screenshot of centos-arm and the right side is the screenshot of windows. can you help me.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bTqm6EMoE9YOR71mVCYrB55uvgUYTMVS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: OK, so this rules out problems with wrong libraries. Next thing to try would be a different java version, e.g. java 11 / 14 or higher. My theory is that this bug is either a java bug, or some Locale or Endianness problem that we haven't thougt about. To find this we would have to create new versions with additional logging and then the best would be to create an issue in JIRA. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX This will probably need several days, if not weeks.

Comment: Hello, I just tried it with jdk11 under centos-arm, and the pictures transferred are good, thank you very much.

Comment: OK then it's a java bug. Consider making a bug report to them. Please answer the question here yourself and mention the exact jdk version that you used successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Under centos-arm, use jdk-11.0.10_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz, and the transferred pictures are good, thanks to the help of Tilman Hausherr.